# Two method arguments or a new class.. for (X and Y cords)

Tags: conventions

In the book 'Clean Code' by Robert C. Martin, he recommends making use of:

Circle makeCircle(Point center, double radius);

over

Circle makeCircle(double x, double y, double radius);

He basically argues that making a class to avoid using multiple method arguments is preferred.

What is your opinions on this? Please explain to me the benefits, or disadvantages of either.

Comment: I don't think this question can have a single, clearly correct answer.

Comment: There are other ways to write this, too. In C++: vector<double> centerCoord, double* centerCoord are some others. Each can have advantages. This question is likely to lead to a style war. One associated topic that also leads to style wars is array-of-structs versus struct-of-arrays. You should consider what sort of larger system you are using, and what sort of conventions are already being used as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few reasons for this.

First, it helps to group parameters meaningfully.  In this trivial example, it's immediately obvious that x and y go together, but it might not be as immediately obvious when dealing with a more obscure example.

Perhaps more importantly, it cuts down on having too many parameters to keep track of meaningfully; once you have a method that takes more than 3 or 4 parameters, it gets more and more cumbersome to keep track of which parameter is which.  Binding parameters together in a class or struct helps avoid that.

Consider this example:

```
int HowManyMinutesToAirport(int AirportIdentifier, string AirportName, int PlainIdentifier, string PlainName, int PlaneSpeed, string PlaneCompassDirection);
```

vs.

```
int HowManyMinutesToAirport(Airport airport, Plane plane);
```

Comment: "it gets more and more cumbersome to keep track of which parameter is which" - and on the other hand, when, at several places in your code, you invariably receive two separate `double` values for the coordinates, and every time you need to pass them on to `makeCircle` from the question, it gets more and more cumbersome to write `new Point(x, y)` instead of `x, y` every single time. And I am sure there is again another exception to that case, etc. - the question is too generic like this; the answer depends a lot on the context.

Comment: In the trivial case I agree this probably isn't necessary.  When you get into cases where you have several parameters to bind together it becomes more meaningful.